# Fleet .NET project. Missing dependencies

Tags: .net, ide, jetbrains-ide, fleet, jetbrains-fleet

I've added a new reference to a .net console project but in the **Solution** tab in Dependencies/Projects, a newly added reference is missing there.
My program .csproj looks like this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DigitalFilterAnalyzer\DigitalFilterAnalyzer.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

The first time I tried import my namespace it showed me a message: "Cannot resolve symbol ...". I did not have any code suggestions for my namespace while typing its name. So I tried to build the current solution and it worked.

But the reference project did not appear in the Dependencies in the Solution tab.

[image]

Comment: Do you have `.sln` file in the opened folder? I guess you have the following structure of the opened folder: https://gist.github.com/ant-druha/55968587804197e1ea77365d826393e3
Without `sln` in `OpenedFolder`. So, only one (random) project is loaded by the dotnet backend actually. We have the issue for this https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/FL-22061/Load-all-projects-in-subfolders-when-there-is-no-sln-file Is this the case?
Or do you initially open one project (`DigitalFilterAnalyzer.Program`) and try to reference another project which is not in the opened folder?

Comment: @Andrey. I've initially opened the DigitalFilterAnalyzer.Program (console app) project and added a reference (using dotnet cli) to the DigitalFilterAnalyzer project which is a class library.

Comment: This is how it works. Fleet backend does not know about `DigitalFilterAnalyzer` if it is not in the workspace.
As far as I can see, VS and VS Code behave the same way. VS just shows the reference in the Solution explorer, but it cannot resolve symbols from the referenced project. Also, `.sln` file is needed to work with multiple projects in Fleet because of the issue I mentioned above.